# How to get next/previous layer in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, tools, function, mapcontrol

I want to create buttons to get next/previous layer but i don't know how to build code to make it possible.

```
var bounds = [[0,0], [2048,2048]];

var floor0 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-00-map.png', bounds),
    floor1 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-01-map.png', bounds),
    floor2 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-02-map.png', bounds),
    floor3 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-03-map.png', bounds),
    floor4 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-04-map.png', bounds),
    floor5 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-05-map.png', bounds),
    floor6 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-06-map.png', bounds),
    floor7 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-07-map.png', bounds),
    floor8 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-08-map.png', bounds),
    floor9 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-09-map.png', bounds),
    floor10 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-10-map.png', bounds),
    floor11 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-11-map.png', bounds),
    floor12 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-12-map.png', bounds),
    floor13 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-13-map.png', bounds),
    floor14 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-14-map.png', bounds),
    floor15 = L.imageOverlay('img/Floor-15-map.png', bounds);

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    minZoom: -1,
    maxZoom: 4,
    layers: floor7,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    fullscreenControlOptions: {
        position: 'topleft'
    }
});

var baseLayers = {
    "Floor +7": floor0,
    "Floor +6": floor1,
    "Floor +5": floor2,
    "Floor +4": floor3,
    "Floor +3": floor4,
    "Floor +2": floor5,
    "Floor +1": floor6,
    "Ground Floor": floor7,
    "Floor -1": floor8,
    "Floor -2": floor9,
    "Floor -3": floor10,
    "Floor -4": floor11,
    "Floor -5": floor12,
    "Floor -6": floor13,
    "Floor -7": floor14,
    "Floor -8": floor15
};


L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet provides these class that you can build off of:

Leaflet.js provides the following classes:

> leaflet-bottom
>   leaflet-top
>   leaflet-left
>   leaflet-right

Generic HTML example:

```
<div id="divmap"> <!--leaflet map wrapper div -->
    <div id="map" > <!--leaflet map div -->
        <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left">
            <div id="marker-legend">  <!-- here the legend -->
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```